# Finding the point on a simplex closest to the origin using GJK's distance subalgorithm

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, computational-geometry

I'm trying to implement the [Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) (GJK), but I'm having problems with the "distance subalgorithm", also known as "Johnson's Algorithm", which is used to determine the point on a simplex that is closest to the origin. I'm getting incorrect results but I can't find any bugs in my code, so the problem must be in my interpretation of the algorithm.

In Johnson’s Algorithm (as described in Gino van den Bergen's book *Collision Detection in Interactive 3D Environments*), the point on the affine hull of a simplex `X = {yi : i ∈ Ix}` closest to the origin is given by:

[image]

Where the Δi^X values are determined recursively in order of increasing cardinality of X:

[image]

... and Δ^X is given by:

[image]

For two dimensions, I find the closest point to the origin using:

```
Point ClosestPointToOrigin(Simplex simplex)
{
    float dx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < simplex.size(); ++i)
        dx += dj(simplex, i);

    Point closest_point(0,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < simplex.size(); ++i)
        closest_point += dj(simplex, i) / dx * simplex[i];

    return closest_point;
}
```

In which the Δi values are determined by:

```
float dj(Simplex simplex, int j)
{
    if (j == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        float d = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
            d += dj(simplex, i) * (simplex[0] - simplex[j]).dotProduct(simplex[i]);

        return d;
    }
}
```

For a simplex `X = {y1, y2}` where `y1 = (1,1)`, `y2 = (1,-1)`, the above code returns `(1.0, -0.333333)`, when the closest point is, in fact, `(1, 0)`.

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but AFAIK a simplex should have `n+1` vertices in dimension `n` so in your example, one vertex is missing, which may cause the problem?

Comment: While it's true that an n-dimensional simplex has n+1 vertices, GJK includes under "simplex" all n-simplices expressible in the chosen coordinate space. In ℝ³, for example, a simplex can be a tetrahedron (3-simplex), a triangle (2-simplex), a line segment (1-simplex), or a point (0-simplex). The line segment example above is therefore OK.

Nevertheless, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Could you post the original mathematical equations? Because there are lot of undefined stuffs in the code you provided such as `I_x` and `I_X`, or `Delta_i` (you defined `Delta_i^X` but not `Delta_i`).

Comment: In the full GJK algorithm, I_x represents a subset of the indices I_y from simplex Y = {y_i : i ∈ I_y}. In that context, the goal is to test all open subsets X of Y and find the one that contains in aff(X) a point also in conv(Y) that is closest to the origin. "Delta_i" and "I_X" are typos (should be "Delta_i^X" and "I_x"), which I have now corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is the `dj` function, maybe you have misunderstood the `dxi` equation or you did not write what you want.

I will try to explain myself, do not hesitate to comment if you do not understand something (I am writing pseudo python code but it should be easily understandable).

Assume I have the following Simplex:

```py
S  = Simplex({
    1: Point (1, 1)  # y1
    2: Point (1,-1)  # y2
})
```

I can immediately compute 2 deltas values:

[image]

Then, I can compute 2 others deltas values:

[image]

[image]

Hopefully by now you'll start to see your mistake: The Δ values are index based, so for each Simplex X of dimension n, you have n Δ values. One of your mistake was to assume that you can compute Δ<sup>X</sup><sub>0</sub> and Δ<sup>X</sup><sub>i</sub> regardless of the content of X, which is false.

Now the last Δ:

[image]

Notice that:

[image]

Once you are here:

[image]

Here is a code written in Python, if you do not understand it, I'll try to write one in a language you understand:

```py
import numpy


class Point(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        return numpy.asarray([x, y]).astype(float).view(cls)

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point ({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

    x = property(fget=lambda s: s[0])
    y = property(fget=lambda s: s[1])


class Simplex(dict):
    def __init__(self, points):
        super(Simplex, self).__init__(enumerate(points))

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Simplex <" + dict.__repr__(self) + ">"


def closest_point(s):
    dx = sum(dj(s, i) for i in range(len(s)))
    return sum(dj(s, i) / dx * v for i, v in s.items())


def dj(s, j):
    if len(s) == 0 or (len(s) == 1 and j not in s):
        print(s, j)
        raise ValueError()
    if len(s) == 1:
        return 1
    ts = s.copy()
    yj = s[j]
    del ts[j]
    return sum(
        dj(ts, i) * (ts[list(ts.keys())[0]] - yj).dot(v) 
        for i, v in ts.items()
    )


S = Simplex([Point(1, 1), Point(1, -1)])

print(closest_point(S))
```